# How to use preloaded images and add to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am trying to download image using jquery and adding downloaded images to DOM. To check if image has been loaded or not i m using "https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded"

For that i have taken a temporary div(temp-images-div) and adding images there.then i am replace the src to actual div (multimedia-div).

```
function populateImageResults(allImagesData) {
    // populate response data for later use 
    responseData = allImagesData;

    //append html as hidden element to body 
    var html = '';
    jQuery.each(responseData, function(index, val) {
        html += '<img id=\"image-'+index+'" src="'+val.THUMBURL+'">';
    });
    html = '<div id="temp-images-div" style="display:none">'+ html + '</div>';
    $('body').append(html);

    $('img[id^="image-"]').imagesLoaded()
        .progress(function (instance, image) {
            var imgId = image.img.id;
            if (image.isLoaded) {
                var imgSrc = image.img.src;
                $('#lemmon-slider-id  ul').append('<li><img id="'+imgId+'" src="'+imgSrc+' style="height:100px"></li>');
            } else {
                // if image not loaded then store broken image id into array
                brokenImageIDs.push(imgID);
            }
        })
        .always(function() {
            // always event will be triggered after all images have been either loaded or confirmed broken
            // currently do nothing
            // FIXME - load broken images here

        });

    // delete temporary div '#temp-images-div'
    jQuery("#temp-images-div").remove();

    // display multimedia div
    jQuery('#multimedia-div').css('display','block');
}
```

Now i am checking Images are being loaded twice. But I want to use pre-loaded image.I can understand why it is loading twice but i do not want this.

So my question is how to use already loaded image? I need to keep the structure of html similar as provided in above jquery code.

```
<Ul>
<li><img ..></li>
<li><img ..></li>
....
...
</ul>
```

Comment: append the new li, then append the existing img to the li.

Comment: how to do it with loading image second time?